# Force full calculation of entire workbook in Coldfusion / Apache POI

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-9

Given a workbook with cross-sheet formulas generated by `Coldfusion 9` via `Apache POI`.

I want to programmatically force an entire workbook to do a "full calculation with dependency tree rebuild" **before** saving the workbook to disk.

So that when my end-users open the spreadsheet, they do not have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>.

How do I accomplish this in `coldfusion`?

**References:**

- http://adobe.ly/HbLBZo
- http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html
- http://bit.ly/HJJA3Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy answer to this one.

**Option 1:**

I think the shortest route is to use [`CreationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html). Unfortunately, it is not available in CF9. That method was added in a later version of POI than the one shipped with CF9. The same applies to `setForceFormulaRecalculation()`. You could probably use the JavaLoader.cfc to load a newer version of POI. Then you would have access to those methods. But that may be more involved than you want for this one task.

**Option 2:**

Failing that, if you know the proper sequence you could iterate through the sheets and recalculate the formulas for each one:

```
wb = sheet.getWorkBook();
evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
// you could also use an array of sheet names instead
for(sheetNum = 0; sheetNum < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNum++) {
    poiSheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNum);
    rows = poiSheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        r = rows.next();
        cells = r.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            c = cells.next();
            if (c.getCellType() == c.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

Another possibility is to populate a template with a macro which automatically [recalculates when the workbook opens](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@poi.apache.org/msg00293.html). The obvious disadvantage is it relies on a macro. But since it is performed by Excel itself, it is probably the most reliable/robust option.

Comment: I've not used ColdFusion for a few years, but for older versions we always used to just remove the old POI jars from the CF lib and drop in the new one instead. Can you not still do that?

Comment: Sure, you still can. I did not suggest it because I have not done it with CF9. It may be fine, but I would recommend some testing first because with all the new functionality there is an increased possibility it might break something else. All depends on how backward compatible the POI versions are.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer ten times, I would.  (I went with Option 2, btw)