# Formula in excel not considering dynamically generated values in cells

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm having a formula in some cells which is based on values in other cells(say A1,B1) which in turn are getting populated from database.My formula is coming correct but it is always considering null value in A1,B1...ie,on opening my excel, the value in cells having formula is always zero..unless I change it in the generated excel.

I want it to consider cell values which are getting dynamically populated and then show the result.Please help!!!!!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9999008/624003

Comment: Did you got what you want?

Answer (score 2):

In case your sheet has some formula for say `A3=sum(A1:A2)` is calculated and it is working fine with A1=5, A2 =4. Now if change the value of A2 with 2 like

```
sh.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue(2);  // set A1=2
```

and perform write operation, check the value of A3 it is still showing 9. It seems wrong but actully not. **The point is that Excel caches previously calculated results and you need to trigger recalculation to updated them.**

```
wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

or with

```
 wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

and then perform Write operation. This will give you the correct result. For Detail check [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)